# Ng-class - apply when URL includes certain string of characters

Tags: angularjs, regex, ng-class

I have the following in my controller;

```
$scope.location = $location.absUrl();
```

This gives me the full URL of the current page being viewed. In my HTML I would like to apply a class if the URL contains a certain parameter.

```
ng-class="{'location': location == }
```

I'm not really sure what to put after the : to evaluate the expression. a url may include a string such as 'requestId=555'

How can I write an expression so that if a URL includes that string the class then gets applied?

Comment: out of `requestId=555` what you wanted to put in `ng-class`? Don't understood it clearly.

Comment: @PankajParkar The URL could contain a parameter like `requestId=555` and if it does I want to apply a class to the HTML element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you are using ui-router**

You can have a state param for the query string. If you inject `$stateParams` into your controller, you can access set `$scope.requestId = $stateParams.requestId`. In your view, you can then bind to `requestId`. To set up the state:

```
$stateProvider.state({
    url: '/someurl?requestId',
    templateUrl: 'someTemplate.tpl.html',
    controller: 'SomeController'
});
```

See [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing).

**If you want plain vanilla js**

According to this highly accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/444610), you can get the query string value of a key with the following function:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

You can then set `$scope.requestId = getParameterByName('requestId');` and bind to it in your template.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not using ui-router in the application.

Comment: I needed to make a small adjustment to bring it into an angular controller:     $scope.getParameterByName = function (name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    };